# How to route within the tab component in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am just a beginner to ionic with some **angular** knowledge.I have tabs template, The Activity tab  will have 3 tab-buttons on the page as shown in  below image:

[image]

As shown in the image when the user click on:

- `about` button, the user  will be routed to `about page`
- `home`  button, the user  will routed to `home page`
- `contact`  button, the user  will routed to `contact  page`

**within tabs page** . This scenario works fine.

Now i have another page called `add-contact`. When the user click on `add-contact` button in `contact` page he must be routed to `add-contact` page along with `tabs-menu` something like this:

[image]

While surfing i got this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875983/ionic-angular-multiple-routes-not-working)**. Here they are routing to other page along with the `clicked object ID` and displaying that object `properties`.

I don't want to perform such operation, I just want to route another page (i,e add-contact) as shown in the 2nd image.

Since `pages` are more, i am giving **[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-azt5hg?file=pages/contact/contact.html)**

Comment: use modal for add new contact. open modal take input and submit get back in contact tab where you will get user input

Answer (score 3):

**NavController is an Ionic V3 navigation method**

See https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/tabs/Tab/ and https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/ for details.

So inside each of the tab root pages you can use

`import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';`

`constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}`

And in your method: 
`this.navCtrl.push(NewPage)` to navigate to a new page.

Here is the modified stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-oykegj

**Ionic V4 primarily uses Angular Routing**

See: https://ionicframework.com/docs/navigation/angular

You'll have to declare routes then use `[routerLink]` to navigate. It's a little more work at the beginning, but quite powerful.

This tutorial runs through how to update your app and why: 
https://www.joshmorony.com/converting-ionic-3-push-pop-navigation-to-angular-routing-in-ionic-4/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am getting this lint error: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavController'` when i use in my app, My app version is ionic - 4.

Comment: In `newContact` function i tried like this ===>`this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/new-contact');`, It  is routing but it is routing  to separate page , not routing inside the `tab-menu`.

Comment: My stackblitz is a forked version of yours. I only made changes in pages/contact/ and app.module.ts. Besides those three files it's exactly the same as yours. I'd look closely at the imports, make sure you are importing it correctly and declaring it in the constructor. The links say v3 but these features work with v4. The part you're interested is in the NavController page under Pushing a View.

Comment: I have mad same changes you did in `app.module.ts` and in `contact` page, Since my app version 4, In contact page i have imported `NavController` like this ====> **import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';** and created its instance in constructor like this: **constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}**  Then in the   `newContact` method i have written like this ===> **newContact(){
    this.navCtrl.push(AddContactPage);
  }**

Comment: I have imported `AddContactPage` in contact page as you imported in the DEMO.

Comment: In my current all pages i,e `contact,home,about` all are under `app` folder  there is no folder called `pages`. Does  it make any issue?

Comment: You're right! Looks like Ionic 4 is moving away from NavController. You should be able to use .goForward - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828017/navcontroller-doesnt-work-in-ionic-4 but the "better" way to do it would be to update to the angular router. It's not hard. I've got to go now, but can update my answer later.

Comment: I have seen this question, In this i am able to `route` but the `tabs menu` will be hidden.It will route completely to `add-contact` page.

Comment: Is your question answered now? I'm not sure what you're looking for. If you want to use the V3 methods - use the nav-controller from ionic-angular.

Comment: My question is not answered, I don't want use v-3. I want the solution for v-4

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the TypeScript file for your 'Contact' page. In this file, you need to create a function that pushes the add-contact page when the 'ADD CONTACT' button is clicked.

Ensure that the NavController has been imported:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Below the import, your code should look something like this:

```
export class ContactPage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

}


addPageLink() {
this.navCtrl.push(addContactPage);
{



{
```

Now navigate back to the HTML page for your 'Contacts' page:

In the code for your 'ADD CONTACT' button, you will need to call the function you just created.

Your code should look similar to this:

```
<button ion-button (click)="addPageLink()">
ADD CONTACT
</button>
```

Now, when the button is clicked, you should be redirected to the 'add-contact' page.

I hope this helps, please let me know how you get on and of course let me know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `module` should be included inside the `route`'s tabs module in order to navigate to another page within the `tabs`. Assuming you have three tabs (`home`, `about` and `contact`), to add a new route (`add-contact`) to the tabs navigation, you have to add the new module into **tabs-routing.module.ts**:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import(...).then(m => m.HomePageModule) },
      { path: 'about', loadChildren: () => import(...).then(m => m.AboutPageModule) },
      { path: 'contact', loadChildren: () => import(...).then(m => m.ContactPageModule) },
      ...
      // set the 'add-contact' route inside the children of tabs route
      { path: 'add-contact', loadChildren: () => import(...).then( m => m.AddContactPageModule) },
    ]
}]
```

Your button inside Contact's page should now specifies the route with `routerLink` to navigate to as follows:

```js
<ion-button [routerLink]="['/add-contact']" routerDirection="forward">Add</ion-button>
```

This way, the `add-contact` page is wrapped by the tabs.